# Не сохраняются данные в Local Storage

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, Не сохраняются данные в Local Storage, помогите пожалуйста

```js
function onPageLoaded() {
    const ul = document.querySelector("ul.todos");

    const addButton = document.querySelector('button.addButton');
    const input = document.querySelector('.input_task');
    const mainDiv = document.querySelector('div.container');

    const changeButton = document.querySelector('i.change');//змінити
    const saveButton = document.querySelector('i.save');//зберегти
    const clearButton = document.querySelector('i.clear')//очистити


    changeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('todos', ul.innerHTML);
    });

    saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('todos', ul.innerHTML);
    });

    clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('todos', ul.innerHTML);
    });


    addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        createTodo();
        //toLocal();
    });
    saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('container', mainDiv.innerHTML);
    });


    //Функция на добавление задачи
    function createTodo() {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('block');
        /*path 1*/
        const div_data = document.createElement('div');
        div_data.classList.add('data');
        const p_data__number = document.createElement('p');
        p_data__number.classList.add('data__number');
        const p_data__time = document.createElement('p');
        p_data__time.classList.add('data__time');



       let date = new Date();
        let day = date.getDate();
        let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        let hours = date.getHours();
        let minutes = date.getMinutes();


        if (day < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }

        if (month <10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        if (hours < 10) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
        }

        if (minutes <10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        let currentDate = day + "." + month + "." + year;
        let time = hours + ":" + minutes;

        p_data__number.innerHTML =  currentDate;
        p_data__time.innerHTML = time;


        /*path 2*/
    const p_block_number = document.createElement('p');
    p_block_number.classList.add('block_number');
    p_block_number.innerHTML = '1';//не запрограммирован счетчик

    /*path 3*/
       const div_block_angle = document.createElement('div');
        div_block_angle.classList.add('block_angle');
        const li_task_wrapper = document.createElement('li');
        li_task_wrapper.classList.add('task_wrapper');
        const i_up = document.createElement('i');
        i_up.classList.add('fa', 'fa-angle-up');
        const i_down = document.createElement('i');
        i_down.classList.add('fa', 'fa-angle-down');

        /*path 4*/
        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.classList.add('todos');
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        const textSpan = document.createElement('span');
        textSpan.classList.add('block_input');
        const newTodo = input.value;
        textSpan.append(newTodo);//Добавляет в спан текст введенный в поле ввода

        /*path 5*/
        const pencilIcon = document.createElement('i');
        pencilIcon.classList.add('fa', 'fa-pencil');

        /*path 6*/
        const checkIcon = document.createElement('i');
        checkIcon.classList.add('fa', 'fa-check');

        /*path 7*/
        const delIcon = document.createElement('i');
        delIcon.classList.add('fa', 'fa-trash');

        /*вывод на экран*/
        /*path 1*/
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(div_data).appendChild(p_data__number);
        //выводим на экран дату
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(div_data).appendChild(p_data__time);
        //выводим на экран время,

        /*path 2*/
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(p_block_number);

        /*path 3*/
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(div_block_angle).appendChild(li_task_wrapper).appendChild(i_up);
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(div_block_angle).appendChild(li_task_wrapper).appendChild(i_down);

        /*path 4*/
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(ul).appendChild(li).appendChild(textSpan);

        /*path 5*/
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(pencilIcon);

        /*path 6*/
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(checkIcon);

        /*path 7*/
        mainDiv.appendChild(div).appendChild(delIcon);

        input.value = "";
        listenDeleteTodo(delIcon);

      
    }

    //Функция удаления задачи
    function listenDeleteTodo(element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            element.parentElement.remove();
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
        //toLocal();
    }

    //Функция для сохранения задач после перезагрузки
    function loadTodos() {
        const data = localStorage.getItem('container');
        if (data) {
            mainDiv.innerHTML = data;
        }
        const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('i.fa-trash');
        for (const button of deleteButtons) {
            listenDeleteTodo(button);
        }
    }
    //Вызываем функцию loadTodos сразу при загрузке страницы
    loadTodos();

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onPageLoaded);







function myData(dateId, timeId) //Выводит дату по клику, РАБОТАЕТ
{
    temp_date = new Date();
    day = temp_date.getDate();
    month = temp_date.getMonth() + 1;
    year = temp_date.getFullYear();
    hours = temp_date.getHours();
    minutes = temp_date.getMinutes();

    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    if (month <10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    if (minutes <10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    document.getElementById(dateId).innerHTML = day + "." + month + "." + year;
    document.getElementById(timeId).innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes;
    //toLocal();
}

// Добавление тасков
const addButton = document.getElementById('add');
    //addButton.className = "button";
const inputTask = document.getElementById('inp');
//inputTask.className = "input_task";
const unfinishedTasks = document.getElementById('unfinished_tasks');
//unfinishedTasks.className = "todos";
const finishedTasks = document.getElementById('finished_tasks');

function createNewElement(task) {
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    let checkbox = document.createElement('span');//Создаем элемент
    checkbox.className = "span_value";//Задаем класс элементу
    checkbox.innerHTML = task;
    //checkbox.innerHTML = "<i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>";
    //Вставляем элемент внутрь - checkbox
    listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
    return listItem;
    //toLocal();
}

function addTask() {
    if (inputTask.value.length > 0) {
        let listItem = createNewElement(inputTask.value);
        unfinishedTasks.appendChild(listItem);
        inputTask.value = "";
    }

addButton.onclick = addTask;
    //toLocal();
}


function changePriorityUp() {
    let priorityValue1 = document.getElementById('1');
        counter = priorityValue1.textContent;
    console.log(priorityValue1);
        if (priorityValue1.textContent < 9) {
           ++counter;
            priorityValue1.innerHTML = counter;
        }
    //toLocal();
}


function changePriorityDown() {
   let priorityValue1 = document.getElementById('1');
    counter = priorityValue1.textContent;
    if (priorityValue1.textContent > 0) {
        --counter;
        priorityValue1.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    //toLocal();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onPageLoaded);
```

```css
*{
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 5% 0 2% 38%;
}
input {
    border: 0;
    color: #bcbcbc;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.input_task {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
    width: 625px;
    height: 24px;
}
.input_add {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 123px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
}

#add {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 110px;
    height: 20;
    background: #0097f4;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.sort {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
.number {
    margin: 5px 20px 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 25px;
    align-items: center;
}
.search{
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 514px;
    height: 38px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a6a6a6;
}
.number p {
    color: #ada6a7;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.fa-sort {
    color: #ada6a7;
    margin: 0 40px;
}
.fa-sort-asc {
    color: #ada6a7;
    margin-bottom: -19px;
}
.fa-sort-desc{
    color: #ada6a7;
    margin-top: -21px;
}
.fa-search {
    color: #ada6a7;
    margin-top: 14px;
    left: -39%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
}
.fa-filter {
    color: #ada6a7;
    margin: 14px 0 0 47px;
}

.block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.data {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 18px 0 10px;
}
.data__number {
    font-size: 135%;
}
.data__time {

}

.block_number {
    padding: 5px 14px;
    margin: 7px 0;
    background: #717171;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 26px;
}
.block_angle {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 7px 10px 0 20px;
}
.block_input {

    color: black;
    width: 516px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.todos {
    height: 55px;
    width: 516px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-top: 18px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    /*display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;*/
}
.block_input2 {
    background: #d1eef4;
    color: black;
    width: 516px;
}
.block_input3 {
    background: #eeeeee;
    color: black;
    width: 516px;
    height: 100px;
}
.fa-angle-up {
    color: #0097f4;
}
.fa-angle-down {
    color: #0097f4;
}
.fa-pencil {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #3f8c3f;
    padding: 11px;
    color: white;
    margin: 8px 12px 0 12px;
    height: 38px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.fa-check {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #0097f4;
    padding: 11px;
    color: white;
    margin: 8px 12px 0 12px;
    height: 38px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.fa-trash {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #0097f4;
    padding: 11px;
    color: white;
    margin: 8px 12px 0 12px;
    height: 38px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.small a {
    padding: 7px 28px;
    font-size: 90%;

}
a.not_active {
    background: #eeeeee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #0097f4;
}
.delete {

    width: 14%;
    height: 99px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 11%;
    top: 29%;
}
.edit {

    width: 21%;
    height: 220px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 29%;
}
h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    font-size: 120%;
}
h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.edit__box {
    background: #fffafa;
    height: 60%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: -10px 0 13px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.line {
    border-right: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
    width: 3px;
    height: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    right: 30%;
    bottom: 43%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- <meta charset="UTF-8"> -->
    <title>Home Work js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0a8ce8c2c2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="container">
    <h1>TODO LIST</h1>
    <div class="input_add">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Task" class="input_task" id="inp">
        <!-- <div class="button">
        </div> -->
        <button class="addButton" onclick="addTask()" id="add">ADD</button>
    </div>
    <div class="sort">
        <i class="fa fa-sort fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="number">
            <i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>123</p>
            <i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <input name="name" value="" class="input_task search">
        <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-filter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block">
        <div class="data">
            <p class="data__number" id="current_date_time_block">12.10.2018</p> <!-- onload="myData()" -->
            <p class="data__time" id="current_time_block">13:24</p>
        </div>
        <p class="block_number" id="1">1</p>
        <div class="block_angle">
            <li class="task_wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-up chengePriorityButton-up" onclick="changePriorityUp()" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down" onclick="changePriorityDown()" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </li>
        </div>
        <ul class="todos" id="unfinished_tasks">
            <li>
                <span onclick="myData('current_date_time_block', 'current_time_block')" class="block_input"
                id="span_value">Вымыть кухню
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil change" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-trash clear" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="delete delete_active">
        <h2>Delete Item?</h2>
        <div class="button small">
            <a class="not_active">NO</a>
            <a>YES</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="edit edit_active">
        <h3>Edit text</h3>
        <div class="edit__box">
            <p>New text of todo item...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button small">
            <a class="not_active">CANSEL</a>
            <a>SAVE</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="line">
    </div>-->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В чём возникла сложность? Добавьте Ваш код сохранения данных в localstorage.

Comment: Уже Добавил код

Comment: Уменьшите Ваш пример в десять раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все Ваши переменные, назначенные в начале `onPageLoaded`, (кроме `mainDiv`) будут указывать на элементы, которых после `mainDiv.innerHTML = ...` уже нет в дереве элементов страницы.

Перенесите `mainDiv.innerHTML = ...` в самое начало функции.