# Не работает плавное появление блока в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста. Хочу сделать чтоб при нажатии на кнопку открывался скрытый блок, а на кнопле менялся текст. Нашел в сети давний код (2012 года) но что то он не так как надо работает, вродь все правильно реализовал. Почему то кнопка сразу скрывается. (вместо скачаного архива jQuery установил потом ссылку).
[Код в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/m2zf4Led/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s').toggle(function() {
    $('#t').show(500);
    $('#s').text('Свернуть');
  }, function() {
    $('#t').hide(500);
    $('#s').text('Більше фото');
  });
});
```

```css
.t_btn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}

.t_btn__block_button {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.t_btn__block_button p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e6ca2e, #f3f36a);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

#t {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>button</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="t_btn">
      <a>
        <div class="t_btn__block_button">
          <p id="s">Більше фото</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="t">
      <img src="https://ki.ill.in.ua/m/670x450/24472749.jpg">
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081903/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-local-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s').click(function() {
    $('#t').toggle(500);
    $('#s').text($('#s').text() == 'Свернуть'? 'Більше фото' : 'Свернуть');
  });
});
```

```css
.t_btn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}

.t_btn__block_button {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.t_btn__block_button p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e6ca2e, #f3f36a);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

#t {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>button</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="t_btn">
      <a>
        <div class="t_btn__block_button">
          <p id="s">Більше фото</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="t">
      <img src="https://ki.ill.in.ua/m/670x450/24472749.jpg">
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Заработало! Спасибки)